# Does removing an object from NSArray automatically release its memory?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks, nsarray

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

myClass *obj = [[myClass alloc] init];

NSArray *ar = [NSArray array];

[ar addObject: obj];

[ar removeObject: obj];

[pool drain];
```

Will removing an object from an NSArray array automatically release its memory that I have earlier allocated?? The answer seems to be yes from what I have found from various sources. The problem is if I test for memory leaks, xcode still complains that obj has not been released. So what's actually going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  When you insert an object into an array, the array retains it (bumps its retain count).  If the object's retain count is 1 (ie, there are no other retains on it) then when it's removed from the array the retain count goes to zero and it's eligible to be deleted.

But your problem in the above scenario is that, after adding the object to the array, you failed to release YOUR retain on the object (due to the alloc/init).  Insert `[obj release]` after the `[ar addObject:obj]`.

(Also note that in your example the entire array will go "poof" when you drain your autorelease pool.)

Comment: "Will removing an object from an NSArray array automatically release its memory that I have earlier allocated??" - strictly the answer is No. It will not release the memory that YOU allocate, merely release the retain that the array itself sent.

Comment: Note that your "also note" may be misleading: the array will be receive `release` when the pool drains, but the objects inside it will live on because they are also owned by something else.

Comment: True, if they are owned by someone else they will continue to exist, in keeping with the "contract" for retain.

Answer (score 3):

Collections retain the objects you add to them, claiming temporary ownership. When you remove an item from the collection, it releases the object (and its temporary claim). In other words, the retain count will be the same before you add an object to a collection and after you remove it.

If that retain count is 0, the memory is reclaimed.

In your code you're allocating an object and claiming ownership of it. That means it has a retain count of 1.

Then you're adding it to the array. The array retains the object, taking temporary ownership and upping its retain count to 2.

You then remove the object from the array. The array releases the object and relinquishes any claim of ownership, bringing the retain count back down to 1.

Since memory is not reclaimed until retain count is back to 0 (nobody has a claim on the object), your object's memory is not reclaimed.

If you had autoreleased the object prior to adding it to the array, or called release on the object after you had removed it (but not both!), the retain count would be 0 and the memory would be reclaimed.

Answer (score 2):

No, you alloc it -> retain count of 1

You add it to the array which sends the object another retain -> 2

You remove the object from the array and the array sends a release -> 1

...so now the retain count is back to 1, which is your initial alloc retain, so you need to release it to free the memory.